# Weird formatting with \lstinline

Tags: listings

I'm writing some documentation about code I wrote and I'm using \lstinline when referring to functions and stuff. 
I'm using the following formatting for my other listings.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=L,
    language=C++,
    showstringspaces=false,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\singlespacing,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
    identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{orange},
}
```

Listings look awesome and work flawlessly, but \lstinline gives me weird formatting:

Code (sorry for german, but you get the issue):

```
Anschließend wird mit der Methode \lstinline|enable()| der Master aktiviert. 
Ab jetzt können DMX-Geräte mit den Methoden \lstinline|setChannelValue(ADRESS, VALUE);| 
einzelne Adressen \lstinline|dmx_master.setChannelRange (START__CHANNEL, END_CHANNEL, VALUE);| 
ganze Bereiche auf den Wert \lstinline|VALUE| umgeschaltet werden.
```

Result: [image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets compilable!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the \singlespacing command in basicstyle caused this behaviour, while keeping the blocks of code well-formatted. Removed it from the default style, now everything looks fine.